# Convert Instance Variable Array to a String

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I get `["a","b","c"]` when I'm trying to get `a,b,c`  (no brackets and quotations).

I'm using a rails form and I'm passing an array for a couple fields.

I've tried `@instancevariable.join(", ")` in views but I keep getting an error saying:

```
undefined method `join' for "[\"a\", \"b\"]":String
```

What am I doing wrong?

Rails Input Form:

```
<%= p.select :item, options_for_select(["a","b","c","d"],selected: p.object.item), {include_blank: "Select", include_hidden: false}, {multiple: true} %>
```

Controller:

```
...
def params
params.require(:random).permit(:other_item, {item: []},)
end
```

Comment: Could you provide the code snippet that sets the value for `@instancevariable`?

Comment: Just added Code Craig.  Thanks! @craig.kaminsky

Answer (score 0):

I think there is just a small error in your strong params definition.

```
params.require(:random).permit(:other_item, item: [])
```

Basically, try without the braces (`{}`).

Comment: No - that's not it.  When I remove curly braces it throws an error in the controller.

Comment: Is `:item` from a different model?

Comment: Nope - definitely same model.